# Stop and Close Tab when 2nd Tab Clicked - jQuery Tabs Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, navigation

I have Tabbed Navigation here: http://jsfiddle.net/EghAt/

When I click Tab 1 it outputs all my list items underneath this tab - Great!
However, if I click Tab 2 while Tab 1 is still outputting, it doesn't close Tab 1 and instead keeps outputting from both.

I would like to close Tab 1 if Tab 2 is clicked and vice-versa.

How do I achieve this with my code?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/BdHf2/2/

Answer (score 0):

While i like you timeouts solution, you could use an alternative where you use a global variable (*gasp*) to store the last clicked `ul`'s id in a variable called `lastClickedId`.

Then, instead of using a delay for your list items to show up, you can use a recursive function to chain the callback of toggleFade so that it calls the next `li` element's fade. In your callback function, you will check if the current list's parent is the same as the `lastClickedId` and if it's true perform the fade for the current `li` element. Otherwise, it breaks the recursion.